# Diferença de {} e = em uma declaração

Tags: c++, sintaxe, declaração-de-variável

Qual a diferença de duas declarações? Em quais ocasiões devo usar cada uma?

```
- int Num{15};
- int Num = 15;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isto chama-se *Uniform Initialization Syntax* ou Sintaxe de Inicialização Uniforme que é a forma preferida para inicializar variáveis em C++ desde a versão 11.

É verdade que a inicialização de tipos simples primitivos assim não muda muito e todo mundo está acostumado usar o operador de atribuição, o que faz mais sentido, então fica até estranho mesmo a forma do UIS. Mas para tipos mais complexos é mais interessante porque ele funciona como uma sintaxe de construção onde passar passar informações e o tipo saberá como inicializar o objeto com essas informações (não vou entrar nesse assunto aqui). Antes até era possível fazer isso com o uso de parênteses, mas acaba confundindo com a chamada de uma função.

Algumas pessoas preferem usar as chaves em tudo para ficar tudo realmente uniforme.

Então está só dizendo que vai criar uma variável de novo `Num` que é do tipo `int` e chamará o construtor desse tipo passando o `15` como argumento para ele se virar para criar o objeto. E o compilador sabe o que fazer neste caso. Se fosse um outro tipo o compilador chamaria um construtor mesmo.

Exemplo:

```
std::vector<int> vetor{10};
```

Aqui está criando a variável `vetor` do tipo `vector` e está passando `10` como argumento. Olhando a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) sabemos que ele tem um construtor que recebe o tamanho que ele deve criar o vetor.

Isto é diferente:

```
std::vector<int> vetor = {10};
```

Aqui está criando a variável e está atribuindo uma lista de dados para o vetor, no caso haverá um elemento com o valor 10.

Eu sei, parece confuso, mas é questão acostumar. C++ começou com alguns erros iniciais e aos poucos foi melhorando a sintaxe. Ao mesmo tempo tem muitas coisas diferentes que precisam ser expressadas.

Mas faça isto:

```
int Num{15.1};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/UniformInitialization.cpp).

Dá erro. Se fizer com a atribuição ele descarta a parte decimal e inicializa com a parte inteira, quase sempre não é o que deseja. Sintaxes novas podem tratar as coisas de uma forma um pouco melhor que as antigas problemáticas.

Em alguns casos pode ser interessante usar essa sintaxe para não ter que dizer qual é o tipo que está criando, por exemplo no retorno em uma função, a sintaxe com as chaves infere o tipo pela assinatura da função.

Pode [ver mais na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization). [Entender mais sobre o problema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) ([mais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_C%2B%2B#Uniform_initialization_syntax)).